# How to invoke Active admin member action from another class or model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an active admin member action on one of the models which renders  pdf file. I want to invoke the same member action but instead of rendering , I want the content to be saved to a file. 
I know render_to_string will help here, but my question is how do I invoke the member action on ActiveAdmin controller. Here is simplified code

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
        member_action :generate_pdf do
        data = get_data
        render :pdf => "generate_pdf", :layout => false, :margin => { top:       0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This is not the solution for the question, but maybe it will help some else.**

If I understand you right you want the same action to display the pdf and to download the PDF? If yes, you can solve this by using a download param `/admin/model/1/generate_pdf?download=1`

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  member_action :generate_pdf do
    data = get_data
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefile.pdf' if params[:download]
    render :pdf => "generate_pdf", :layout => false, :margin => { }
  end
end
```

Comment: No I dont want to download pdf. Basically I want to generate pdf as file programatically, so that I can attach it to a mail. Is there any way we can invoke the rendering logic and save it as file?

Comment: There is no way in active admin to do that. Maybe ActionMailer can do that.